# Netica -> R (bnlearn) Import

Tags: r

Is there a way to import Bayesian networks created with Netica into R?
My version of Netica writes 2 formats: .neta and .dne
I have checked the bnlearn package in R, which provides the following file I/O functions:

read.bif and write.bif
read.dsc and write.dsc
read.net and write.net

From the documentation:

> Most of the networks present in the Bayesian Network Repository have an associated BIF file that can be imported with read.bif. HUGIN can import and export NET files; Netica can read (but not write) DSC files; and Genie can read and write both DSC and NET files.

So, is it possible to work with (i.e. train, manipulate) models created in Netica in R?